# take template basis on run-time value

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, constant-expression

I have an `enum`:

```
enum operation {
 plus,
 delete
 //...
}
```

There is function, which has a **run-time** argument.

```
operation_do(plus);
```

And inside that function, there is a template-function call, which is based on a run-time argument.
Important: I can NOT make `operation_do()`, as a template function. This is the condition.

```
void operation_do(operation op) {
    call<op>();
}
```

I have a compiled error: `op` is not a constant expression.

I tried to resolve this with the help function, like this:

```
constexpr operation get(operation arg) {
    return arg;
}

void operation_do(operation op) {
    constexpr operation elem = get(op);
    call<elem >();
}
```

But it is still the same error: `op` is not a constant expression.
Can anyone help, please, with this?

Comment: A template cannot be based on a run time value. You better revisit your design.

Comment: That is not what templates are for.

Comment: FYI, compile-time is contrasted to run-time, which is when the program executes. Real-time is something else, specifically about timing & scheduling constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And inside that function, there is a template-function call, which is based on a real-time argument. Important: I can NOT make operation_do(), as a template function. This is the condition.

This is the problem.

In C++ a run-time value (so a function argument, that can be a run-time value) can't be used as template parameter.

For the same reason can't works the passage through a `constexpr` value

```
void operation_do(operation op) {
    constexpr operation elem = get(op); // <--- error
    call<elem >();
}
```

because `elem` can't be initialized from a run-time value.

The best I can imagine is the use of a sequence of `if` (or, maybe better, a `switch`) to pass from a run-time value to a compile-time value.

Something as

```
void operation_do (operation op)
 {
   switch ( op )
    { 
      case plus:
         call<plus>();
         break;

      case del:
         case<del>()
         break;
    }
 }
```

Obviously this is acceptable only if the number of the enum value is limited and if  you can concentrate the `switch` in a single place.

Note that `delete` is a keyword, so you can't use it as an identifier.